# Video and Audio playlist and syncing with HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement.js, popcornjs

I have 5 audio recordings, and 5 video recordings of the same length. I'd like to play them back in a random order, and allow track skipping, and keep them in sync. After all 5 have played it should stop.

Ideally I'd also like to host everything on Youtube. I've tried a few solutions but nothing quite works.

- mediaelement.js doesn't like me setting the source after the fact from Youtube
- popcorn.js I can't figure out how to make two random playlists that sync
- regular HTML5 I can't retrospectively set a new iFrame for Youtube

If anyone has a way into this task that would be great!

Comment: How about leaving out YouTube and using either plain HTML5 media or a somewhat simpler library like jPlayer? By the way: Popcorn is partly based on jPlayer.

Comment: Tried that -- the problem is then I have to do my own buffering code that manages two things which might both slow down. I would be happy with either solution at this point though!